# Custom form in facebook page

Tags: html, facebook

I've a html signup form. So I want to integrate this form to my Facebook page. Here is the facebook page link. In this page you can see a email address field box which get the user email address to subscribe to our list.

**Facebook Page:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/North-Scottsdale-Real-Estate
/462597977169342?id=462597977169342&sk=app_161293083930879
```

**Here is my form:**

```
http://creativeartbd.com/bens/newsletter-template.html
```

How can i integrate this form to my facebook page? any idea or help.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: you can achieve this using a Facebook API

Comment: @user123_456, which Facebook API i use and how ?