# How can i integrate custom html form in facebook page

Tags: html, facebook

I want to integrate a html signup form to my Facebook page. In this page you can see a email address field box which get the user email address to subscribe to our list.

**Facebook Page address:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/North-Scottsdale-Real-Estate
/462597977169342?id=462597977169342&sk=app_161293083930879
```

**Here is my form link:**

```
http://creativeartbd.com/bens/newsletter-template.html
```

How can i integrate this form to my facebook page? any idea or help.
Thank you so much for your help.

Note: This is my second post of this question because of I didn't get answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [Custom form in facebook page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575401/custom-form-in-facebook-page). Your impatience is not an excuse to post the same question again after half a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this link ? https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/

it should solve your issue

Comment: how it's working with my custom form. In my page there is a email address field which facebook provided. But How can i integrate my form email field to get user email. any idea ?